# C++ abstract class static methods showing in derived classes

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, static, abstract-class

I'm coming from a C# background and now trying to pick up C++.  I'm using an abstract class that has a static member to keep track of the total number of that object type, and a static method to get the count. for example:

```
class Shape
{
public:
     virtual void Draw() = 0;
     static int GetShapeCount();
private:
     static int mShapeCount;
};
```

I noticed that derived classes are also able to call the abstract class static method, which I found a little curious/confusing.  For instance, someone might get confused if they are able to do something like:

```
Shape *newShape = new Rectangle();
cout << newShape->GetShapeCount();
```

Does that mean get rectangle count or shape count? I also noticed that even if you don't explicitly call it a shape you can still access the static method through derived classes:

```
Rectangle rectClass = Rectangle();
cout << rectClass.GetShapeCount();
```

So my question is two-fold:

1)Why/How is this possible
2)Is there a way to not allow derived classes to call abstract class static methods?

Edit:

my test that I ran in C# was incorrect, and it shows similar behavior... it just seems odd to me that the static methods would fall through to the derived classes as well.  It seems consistent though with other languages, and I suppose I just made a mistake.

Comment: It is a public method, it is not hidden from *anything* in your code. Why would it be hidden from derived classes?

Comment: my question is why can i call a static method in an abstract class from a derived class, not why isn't it hidden

Comment: @DavidTorrey (public) static methods are static methods, are static methods, period! _'Is there a way to not allow derived classes to call abstract class static methods?'_ Yes, make the method `private` or `protected`!

Comment: @DavidTorrey _'... in C# a quick test shows'_  Using c# test code is unlikely to reproduce any c++ behavior!

Comment: static methods are meant to be independent of non-static members of an object (the object's personal data).  THis means that GetShapeCount() will give the same result, whatever shape calls it.  So it's definitively the shape count and not the rectangle count !

Comment: `Does that mean get rectangle count or shape count?` Why is this confusing? It's called "GetShapeCount", so it seems pretty obvious that it is the shape count.

Comment: @DavidTorrey There be language difference. I am far blind of C#. But I can say the say C++ implemented static methods are the so great. Forget about C++ or C#, philosophically your argument is incorrect. Once, you mention GetShapeCount as static as the name implies, it gets the count of how many shapes underneath. It could be triangle, circles, rectangle or whatever. On the other hand public means public; You can access those members from anywhere. I mean in any language, if a public member can't be assessed from anywhere, it a wrong. I don't know the case of C#.

Comment: you are all correct, i just incorrectly thought that inheritence was different for static methods.  I thought that static methods were not inherited originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, C++ doesn't have polymorphic static functions, so supposing `static getShapeCount()` was implemented as `return mShapeCount;`, it will return the base class value. However this could be easily simulated using CRTP and static polymorphism. Since is not a good practice to call static functions from objects instead of the class itself, this works like a charm.

> I also noticed that even if you don't explicitly call it a shape you can still access the  static method through derived classes

You have declared `getShapeCount()` public, isn't? And you (I suppose, again, because you haven't showed us enough code) have used public inheritance.

Comment: but why can i call this static method from a derived class?

Comment: shouldn't i only be able to call the static method from the base class Shape?  I don't see why i'd be able to call the Shape static method from Rectangle

Comment: @DavidTorrey why? You declared the function as `public`. You inherited the base class using public inheritance. Thus your derived class has access to the base class method. And since its public on the base its public on the derived one. Note that this is exactly the same behaviour of C#...

Comment: `I don't see why i'd be able to call the Shape static method from Rectangle` That is the _entire_ purpose of inheritance. I don't understand why this is so baffling to you.

Comment: i suppose i thought that inheritence was different for static methods

Answer (score 2):

```
Shape *newShape = new Rectangle();
cout << newShape->GetShapeCount();
```

is a way to write `cout << Shape::GetShapeCount()`.

as

```
Rectangle rectClass = Rectangle();
cout << rectClass.GetShapeCount();
```

is a way to write `cout << Rectangle::GetShapeCount()` which turns into `Shape::GetShapeCount()`.

If you want to prohibit `Rectangle::GetShapeCount()`
you may add a deleted function (C++11):

```
class Rectangle : public Shape
{
public:
// Previous methods

    static int GetShapeCount() = delete; // forbid the usage Rectangle::GetShapeCount()
};
```

Comment: +1 I'm glad to see that the times when C++11 is considered C++, not another freaks-only version, have begun. Well, three years have spent, isn't?

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed that derived classes are also able to call the abstract class static method, which I found a little curious/confusing.

This is the same behavior that you have in C#: derived classes have access to all methods of their base class, as long as their visibility (public, protected, internal, etc.) allows for it.

> Does that mean get rectangle count or shape count?

It's the shape count, because all derived classes share the same counter.

> Is there a way to not allow derived classes to call abstract class static methods?

Yes - you can hide a method from derived classes by making it `private`.

If you would like to keep separate object counts per derived class, you can make a static `map<type_index,int>`, and increment the counter of your specific type. However, you wold need to give your `static` method an access to the type of the caller.

Comment: *"you can make a static map<type_index,int>, and increment the counter of your specific type."* That could be achieved easily using CRTP, no need for RTTI.

Comment: yep. You are right. Sorry. The point was to not use RTTI for this. On the other hand, its other way to solve this, and possibly easier for C++ nobels.